# Sonar-qube project details disclosed dispite of Login credentials

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-web

I am able to see project details on Sonarqube UI screen in spite of my login credentials.
Is there any settings I need to change so that I can see all this details only after I login.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two solutions :

- Either you force users to be authenticated in order to access to SonarQube => Activate the "Force user authentication" setting
- Or you change permission of projects to remove the "Anyone" group => more details in the [doc](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization)

Comment: Another question-- Can we create logins for leads?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: can I create separate logins to each set of Projects

Comment: You can create as much logins as you want.

Comment: Can you pass me relevant URL to work on this scenario

Comment: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-User